# Do Ice Pops do anything?

Tags: tales-of-xillia

Supposedly in Tales of Graces eating Ice Pops would grant (possibly temporary) [stat boosts](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/604158-tales-of-graces-f/64656446). There are Ice Pops in Tales of Xillia as well but they don't seem to serve any purpose.

Their description says they heal 10% of your health and give you a Win Stick or a Lose Stick. With a Win Stick you can get a free Ice Pop. I haven't seen any hint of them having any other purpose but after hearing about Tales of Graces I find it hard to believe that they do nothing.

So does anybody know if they do anything else?

Comment: That link sounds more like trolling than reliable.

Comment: I want to believe that they do something else since they are otherwise useless. They aren't even a cheap alternative to anything as far as I can tell lol.

Comment: I sincerely doubt the Ice Pops do anything but what they say they do.  You might get something if you get enough win sticks, but that's just speculation on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not do anything but give you Win Sticks and Lose Sticks. A Win Stick will get you a free Ice Pop from the same vendor. But that is it.

Answer (score -2):

They are part of an ingredient in custom made items and also food custom made items

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  I don't recall using these anywhere throughout my entire playthrough.